# How to initialize CKRecord with both zoneID and recordID?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm currently building a solution to sync `Core Data` records to `CloudKit`.

I need help to find out it what I want to do with `CKRecord` is feasible.

I’ve checked the Apple CloudKit documentation, experiment and searched the web,  but I didn’t find the kind of answer I want.

I would like to initialize the  CKRecord with having `zoneID` and also `recordID` that I would supply in init method.
The initializer seems to force me to choose between the two.  I
want to create my own ZoneID (not using default),  and also set the  `recordID` instead of having it being autogenerated.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify both a zone ID and a record ID, but you need to do it in three steps:

First, create a `CKRecordZoneID` with your zone ID and user:

```
let ckRecordZoneID = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "myZone", ownerName: CKOwnerDefaultName)
```

Then you can created a `CKRecordID` with your required record ID and specifying your `CKRecordZoneID`:

```
let ckRecordID = CKRecordID(recordName: recordIDString, zoneID: ckRecordZoneID)
```

Finally you can create the `CKRecord` using that record ID:

```
let ckRecord = CKRecord(recordType: myRecordType, recordID: ckRecordID)
```

Comment: You can see how I do this here: https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3/blob/master/Sources/Classes/NSManagedObject%2BCKRecord.swift

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension on CKRecord so code changes were minimal:

```
extension CKRecord {
    static func with(recordType: CKRecord.RecordType, zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID) -> CKRecord {
        let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: UUID().uuidString, zoneID: zoneID)
        return CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: recordID)
    }
}
```

so instead of this (old broken way):

```
let myRecord = CKRecord(myType, zoneID: myZoneId)
```

it becomes:

```
let myRecord = CKRecord.with(myType, zoneID: myZoneId)
```

Note that the original method would generate a record name for you and I did that using UUID, which is probably the most standard way nowadays. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Previously it was possible to initialize a CKRecord using a recordID and zoneID. However this has been deprecated:

```
 @available(swift, introduced: 4.2, deprecated: 4.2, message: "Use init(recordType:recordID:) + CKRecord.ID(zoneID:) instead")
public convenience init(recordType: CKRecord.RecordType, zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID)
```

However it seems that it is possible to do it this way using an undocumented and therefore I assume unreliable initializer:

```
let recordID = CKRecord.ID(zoneID: myZoneID) //This initializer is not documented!!! 
let record = CKRecord(recordType: "aString", recordID: recordID)
```