# Correct Way to Initialize New CKRecord

Tags: cloudkit

I am using Realm for my local cache in a Mac app, and CloudKit for sync. Up until now, I have been initializing `CKRecord` objects like this:

```
let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Workspace", recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: workspace.recordName, zoneID: "..."))
```

The object `workspace` is my locally cached object and its `recordName` matches the `CKRecord`'s `recordName`.

I recently learned about `encodeSystemFields` and that I need to store the record's metadata in my local cache. But as far as I can tell, the only way to initialize an object with that meta data is like this:

```
let coder = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: object.recordData!)
coder.requiresSecureCoding = true
let record = CKRecord(coder: coder)
coder.finishDecoding()
```

But if I initialize my `CKRecord` with `coder`, how can I specify my `recordID` and `zoneID`?

Comment: Clifton, its you again. You when I see the word coder, and the keyword NSKeyedUnarchiver; I think of the new Codable protocol in Swift 4.0. Maybe completely unrelated, but well ... you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only going to be using that initializer if you already have a record (you're modifying or deleting).  The encoded system fields contain that information so you don't need to specify that directly. If you're creating a new record you  will use one of the other initializers to generate those specifically, for example [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429133/how-to-initialize-ckrecord-with-both-zoneid-and-recordid?rq=1).

So for example in my app when making a record to sync with iCloud I just check for the existence of metadata, and if it is there I use CKRecord(coder:), otherwise CKRecord(recordType: recordID:) like so:

```
if let ckMetaData = object.value(forKey: Schema.GenericFieldNames.ckMetaData) as? Data
{
    // MetaData exists

    if self.debug
    {
        print(" RecordFromObject \(self.objectName) We have Metadata. This will update an existing record in iCloud")
    }

    let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: ckMetaData)
    unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
    self.outputRecord = CKRecord(coder: unarchiver)

}
else
{
    // No MetaData

    if self.debug
    {
        print(" RecordFromObject \(self.objectName) We have no Metadata.   This record will be new to iCloud!")
    }

    let objectID = object.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
    let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: objectID, zoneID:  self.inputRecordZoneID)
    self.outputRecord = CKRecord(recordType: object.entity.managedObjectClassName, recordID: recordID)
}
```

Comment: Okay, perfect. That's what I'll do. Thanks for your help!